# Google Drive: Orphaned file script is stopping before it has all files

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api

I have the below script and its cutting out at about 214 files recovered and sent to the new orphaned folder when I have over 2000 orphaned. I would appreciate any advice

```
function myFunction(findOrphaned) {
 var allFiles = DocsList.getAllFiles();
 var orphaned = DocsList.getFolder('Orphaned');
 for (var i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
   if (allFiles[i].getParents().length === 0) {
     allFiles[i].addToFolder(orphaned);
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that the API you are using appears to have been deprecated.  See near the bottom of this post:  http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2014/12/speeding-up-htmlservice.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you're attempting, using the newer DriveApp API since, as rchang pointed out, the DocsList API is deprecated and set to be decommissioned in April.

```js
   function collectOrphans(findOrphaned) {
   var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Orphaned').next();
   var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
   var orphanCount = 0;
   while(files.hasNext()){
      var file = files.next();
      if(!file.getParents().hasNext()){
        folder.addFile(file);
        orphanCount++;      
      }
    }
    Logger.log('Moved ' + orphanCount + ' orphans successfully.');
}
```